# Minimizing a distance to a set on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projection

We are on E  the vector space  of continuous and 2 times differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ i.e., $C^2[0,1].$
I have the sets
$V = f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$  and   $W = f$ such that $f=f''.$
And the function 
$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1[{f(t)g(t)+f'(t)g'(t)}]\,dt.$
I have proven that they are complementary subspaces and that they are orthogonal by a scalar product defined as above.

With that I will be able to find the orthogonal projection of any function on $W.$

Now if I'm given another set $G_{a,b} = f$ such that $f(0)=a$   and $f(1)=b$ how can I determine 
$$\inf_{f\in G_{a,b}}\int_0^1\left[f^2(t)+f'^2(t)\right]dt?$$

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the norm induced by the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle.$

I know it's the same as 
$$\left(\inf_{f\in G_{a,b}} {\|f\|}\right)^{\!2}$$
and  that 
$$\inf_{f\in G_{a,b}}{\|f\|}$$
is $d(0,G)$ which is the projection of $0$ on $G.$

But $G$ is not even a subspace; I really don't know how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please explain what the notation $\|\cdot\|_{<>}$ means? That is non-standard notation in functional analysis.

Comment: Sorry I just meant the norm associated to the scalar product <>

Comment: Oh, you probably don't need to write that in there. Or if you think there might be confusion, you can just insert language like, "Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the norm induced by the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle.$"

Comment: Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Calculus of Variations here. Let
$$L(f,\dot{f};t)=f^2(t)+\dot{f}^2(t). $$
Then the Euler-Lagrange equation says that you must set
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}+\frac{d}{dt}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{f}}=0. $$
This becomes
\begin{align*}
2f+\frac{d}{dt}\left(2\dot{f}\right)&=0\\
f+\ddot{f}&=0\\
f(t)&=A\sin(t)+B\cos(t).
\end{align*}
Applying $f(0)=a$ shows us that $B=a,$ so we rewrite as
$$f(t)=A\sin(t)+a\cos(t).$$
Applying $f(1)=b$ shows us that
\begin{align*}
b&=A\sin(1)+a\cos(1)\\
b-a\cos(1)&=A\sin(1)\\
b\csc(1)-a\cot(1)&=A.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$f(t)=\left[b\csc(1)-a\cot(1)\right]\sin(t)+a\cos(t). $$